# how can i calculate AUC of each folds in R caret package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I need to calculate the confusion matrix and AUC of each fold. Using caret package in R.
For the confusion matrix, everything is okay. But for calculating AUC, I have this error :
undefined columns selected
is there another way to calculate AUC?

```
df$ximp<-df$ximp[sample(nrow(df$ximp)),]

#Create 5 equally size folds
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(df$ximp)),breaks=5,labels=FALSE)

#Perform 5fold cross validation - random forest
importance=list()
for(i in 1:5){
  #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData <- df$ximp[testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- df$ximp[-testIndexes, ]
  rf_fit <- train(Vital_status ~ ., 
                  data = trainData, 
                  method = "ranger",
                  importance = 'permutation')
  pred=predict(rf_fit, testData,type="prob")
  paste("###### fold 1")
  print(confusionMatrix(pred, testData$Vital_status))
  a=varImp(rf_fit)
  importance[[i]] <- a
  auc(testData$Vital_status,as.numeric(pred[2]),direction="<", levels = levels(df$ximp$Vital_status))
  par(pty="s")
  roc(testData$Vital_status,as.numeric(pred),plot = TRUE,precent=TRUE,print.auc=TRUE,legacy.axes=TRUE,percent=TRUE,
      col="#4daf4a",main = paste("ROC of random forest fold",i))
}
```

Comment: if you are using pROC package, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.17.0.1/topics/auc on how to use `auc`, i suspect you are not using it correctly